# Bayesian error (Toeplitz approximation of a correlation matrix dimension mismatch with class number)

Tags: bayesian, measurement-error

I like to solve the question of part 1 of this question form  [Introduction to Statistical Pattern Recognition, 2nd Edition](https://www.elsevier.com/books/introduction-to-statistical-pattern-recognition/fukunaga/978-0-08-047865-4) which is:

> Repeat Problem 7 for a two-dimensional random field of nxn. The verti-
>   cal and horizontal correlation matrices are the same and specified by
>   (4.126).

[image]

and the question 7 is :

> Two stationary normal distributions are characterized by `...` where R is given in (4.126). (a) Compute the Bayes error for

```
n = 10, A = 2, o2 = 1, and p = 0.5
```

. (b) Using the same numbers as in (a), compute the

> error when `...` are used to design the
>   classifier and `...` are used to test the
>   classifier.

[image]

and 4.126 equation is:

[image: di]

SO i tried to write some matlab codes based of [this](https://github.com/timmy00274672/BayesClassifier) codes like this:

```
n=10;delta=2;
m0=zeros(1,n);m1=delta*ones(1,n);
m=[m0;m1];
S1=1*eye(2);
%S=zeros(n,n);
%S(0.5,:)=S1;S(:,0.5)=S1;
roa=0.5
r = [1 roa^1 roa^2 roa^3 roa^4 roa^5 roa^6 roa^7 roa^7 roa^8 roa^9];
S=toeplitz(r)

P=[0.5,0.5]'; N=500;
randn('seed',0)
[X,y]=generate_gauss_classes(m,S,P,N);

%The data set X 1 is generated similarly:
randn('seed',100);
[X1,y1]=generate_gauss_classes(m,S,P,N);
%where randn is initialized using seed = 100.


%Step 1. To compute the ML estimates of the mean values and covariance matrix (common to all three
%classes), use Gaussian_ML_estimate by typing
class1_data=X(:,find(y==1));
[m1_hat, S1_hat]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(class1_data);
class2_data=X(:,find(y==2));
[m2_hat, S2_hat]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(class2_data);
class3_data=X(:,find(y==3));
[m3_hat, S3_hat]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(class3_data);
S_hat=(1/3)*(S1_hat+S2_hat+S3_hat);
m_hat=[m1_hat m2_hat m3_hat];



%For the Bayesian classifier, use function bayes_classifier and provide as input the matrices m,
%S, P, which were used for the data set generation. In other words, use the true values of m, S, and P
%and not their estimated values. Type
z_bayesian=bayes_classifier(m,S,P,X1);


%To compute the error probability for each classifier, compare the vector y 1 of the true class labels
%of the vectors of X 1 with vectors z_euclidean, z_mahalanobis, and z_bayesian, respectively. For
%each comparison, examine the vector elements in pairs and count the number of matches (i.e., correct
%classifications); divide by the length of y 1 . Type

err_bayesian = (1-length(find(y1==z_bayesian))/length(y1));
```

to solve it similar to this sample :

[image]
 and

[image]

so i don't understand how it could have n=8 and which made 8x8 covariance matrix like this:

[image]

which means i must have 8 class but the question said i have 2 class, so what part i of the question i don't understand?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it not focused enough?!